# Discrete Mathematics: Prove that f(x) is in O(x)

Tags: asymptotics

- Prove that $$\frac{2x^{2}+x}{x+1}$$ is in $O(x)$

Comment: Those tags have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: My naive way is just to say that $f(x) = O(x^2)/O(x) = O(x)$ but that is probably too fast

Comment: @Nameless sorry it was my mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: @A̷n̷d̷y̷: please next time show what you have tried

Comment: Well I am confused that's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, we have that

$$\frac{2x^2+x}{x+1}=\mathcal O(x)\iff \exists\,\text{a constant}\;M\;\;s.t.\;\;\left|\frac{\frac{2x^2+x}{x+1}}x\right|=\left|\frac{2x+1}{x+1}\right|\le M$$

But we know that

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{2x+1}{x+1}=2\;,\;\;\;\text{ so}\ldots$$

Comment: Great Answer. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2 x^2 +x}{x+1} <\frac{2x^2 +x^2}{x}=3x=O(x)$.

Comment: Can you please show more of your work.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x+1}<\frac{1}{x}, x< x^2$ for $x >1$

Comment: In the sense of large $x$, the inequality follows. Now $M = 3$ is your constant.

Comment: Sorry,the prove must use the definition of O(x).

Comment: Take the limit of your function and $3x$ as $x \to \infty$. What do you get?